# Ejecutar de forma asíncrona una función síncrona en javascript (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asincronismo

Esta es la función. Como es síncrona, en el momento de llamarla es ignorada (la llamo dentro de un Ajax). ¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutarla como si fuera asíncrona? ¿O de convertirla en asíncrona? Gracias.

```
function fetchHeader(url, hdr) {
  try {
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("HEAD", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    if(req.status== 200){
        return req.getResponseHeader(hdr);
    }
    else return false;
} catch(er) {
    return er.message;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con que se ignora? Al ser síncrona la ejecución se debería parar hasta obtener una respuesta o un error

Comment: La llamo así dentro de un ajax:                                                                   
**var lastDte = fetchHeader(dirGen+json[i],'Last-Modified');**                                y devuelve:                                                                                                                  `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Answer (score 6):

El último parámetro de la función [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) tienes que especificarle `true` para que ejecute la petición asincronamente.

Cambia:

```
req.open("HEAD", url, false);
```

Por:

```
req.open("HEAD", url, true);
```

Como la peticion es asincrona, siempre te retornara `false` ya que el `statusCode` sera asignado cuando el servidor envie una respuesta lo que puede tomar tiempo.

Para poder obtener el resultado tienes que hacer cambios y uno de esos es registrar un callback para recibir el resultado cuando el servidor envie la respuesta. Osea, la funcion se ejecutara cuando se reciban dados de la funcion:

```
function fetchHeader(url, hdr, callback) {
  try {
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() { // se ejecuta cuando recibimos respuesta del server
       if(this.status == 200) {
         // si es exitoso se ejecuta el callback definido con los parametros
         callback(req.getResponseHeader(hdr), req);
       }
    }
    req.open("HEAD", url, true);
    req.send(null);

  } catch(er) {
    return er.message;
}
```

Entonces el uso de la funcion seria la siguiente:

```
fetchHeader("url","hr", function(header, request) {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     alert(header);
  }
  else {
    alert("respuesta fallida");
  }
});
```

Comment: Lo probé, y me devuelve false entonces :/

Comment: Dale una mirada a la respuesta que la actualize.

Comment: Lo he probado y no llama al callback..y sale que response no esta definido por eso. Pero muchas gracias igualmente tío!